# Can an online store say they don't have a refund policy as part of their customer agreement?

Tags: online-shopping, customer-service

I am not sure this is the right place to ask. So please let me know in a comment if it is not and I will delete the question.

I have seen some online stores that sell digital content and don't have a refund policy, i.e. they don't offer refunds. Is that really "possible" or "legal", or is just a way to discourage you from requesting a refund?

For example, if they falsely advertise a product, and once you purchase it, you see that the advertisement was deceiving. Also, when we buy clothes in a physical store, we are able to try them on and don't buy them blind. This isn't the case with downloadable content.

I'm located in Argentina.

Comment: Where are you located? In the US, no store or vendor is required to offer a refund policy, I don't think.

Comment: Digital (or non-tangible) products are rarely refundable

Comment: @Dzyann - I forgot that you're located in Argentina, per your last question.

Comment: It's common that a store needs to state their policy, but online or brick, they can have a no-refund policy. Software and its function are a different issue I think.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Digital content is a different beast than physical content, because usually you just buy a license to access the content.  You may download it, but you're not allowed to send it to someone else.

Some eBook authors will offer a money-back guarantee after, say, 30 days, or even longer.  If the content is good, it's usually a good idea to do this.  The marketing term for this is *risk reversal* and it takes down the barrier of "what if I don't like this" and encourages you to buy it to look at it.  You should factor this in before you buy a digital product.

Having said that, if you used a Visa card, and if the product truly was awful and misleading, you may be able to [charge back the transaction](http://usa.visa.com/merchants/operations/chargebacks_dispute_resolution/index.html).

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I was asking because it makes no sense to me they enforce so much conditions. Specially the Game industry is rather common to buy a new game and find tons of users with issues that have to be troubleshooting for hours to use a product they bought. Maybe 60 dollars is not that much of an investment. But it just feels wrong the attitude some of this places have towards their clients. I like what you say about risk reversal.

Comment: About the refund itself, although they don't have a refund policy, by the Customer rights don't I have anyway the right to contest their service and request the money back? Maybe they don't accept it or have a channel for it, but if I really wanted that I should be able to get a laywer or something and try and make my rights valid no? Requesting it to the Credit card is a way to achieve it but I was talking to deal directly with the seller. I am just trying to understand the whole picture. Thank you!!!